# GroupBy a property, make a list of the repeated ones

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list with some records, which some have the same record ID. I want to group by that record ID, and have the rest of the properties to be Lists and some strings. This is the object I'm hoping to create:

```
public class Product {
    public string Id{ get; set; }
    public List<string> Package { get; set; }
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And the records I want to process come like this:

```
list_Of_Records = [ { id: 123, Package: ABC, ShortDescription: Description },
                    { id: 123, Package: ZXY, ShortDescription: Description },
                    { id: 123, Package: MLO, ShortDescription: Description },
                    { id: 456, Package: ABC, ShortDescription: DescriptionTwo },
                    { id: 456, Package: ZXY, ShortDescription: DescriptionTwo },
                    { id: 456, Package: MLO, ShortDescription: DescriptionTwo },
]
```

And I´d like to look something like this:

```
list_Of_Records_Organized = [
        { Id: 123, Package: [ABC, ZXY, MLO], ShortDescription: Description },
        { Id: 456, Package: [ABC, ZXY, MLO], ShortDescription: DescriptionTwo }
]
```

The description is always the same for each ID, so I can take any of the three. The problem is those packages!

Hope I'm being clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var list_Of_Records_Organized =
    from r in list_Of_Records
    group r by r.Id into g
    select new Product {
        Id = g.Key,
        Package = g.Select(r => r.Package).ToList(),
        ShortDescription = g.First().ShortDescription
    };
```

Or in Lambda syntax:

```
var list_Of_Records_Organized = list_Of_Records.GroupBy(
    r => r.Id,
    (k, g) => new Product {
        Id = k,
        Package = g.Select(r => r.Package).ToList(),
        ShortDescription = g.First().ShortDescription
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! This works! Had to change the SelectMany to Select, and add a ToList, but works perfectly.

Comment: @fede_rosario Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought `r.Package` was a `List<string>`. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Yes, I did the same. If the idea was to have List<Product> and then a new List<Product> with grouped Package values, then Package must be a List<string> and SelectMany would be needed. I wrote same query but no point posting as this answer handles it perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

```
organizedList = list_of_records
                .GroupBy(m => m.id)
                .Select(m => new {
                   Id = m.Key,
                   Package = m.SelectMany(x => x.Package).ToArray(),
                   ShortDescription = m.First().ShortDescription
                });
```

But this means you will take an arbitrary ShortDescription (the first found in each group).

By the way, your sample is not clear.

Is Package a string or a list of string ? In your class, it's a `List<string>`, but in your sample it looks like a string.

if it's a string, use Select instead of SelectMany in

```
Package = m.Select(x => x.Package).ToArray(),
```

Comment: Yes, its a list, sorry about that. Both answers work, marking the one I tried first.